# Mobile Performance Testing for Unique ID for particular device,here i am not having the user credentials,How to do user Load testing?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Mobile Performance Testing for Unique ID for a particular device, here I am not having the user credentials, How to do Load testing with different credentials? and Increase more user load?

Answer (score 0):

You may not get around obtaining or creating the credentials of those multiple test user accounts.

Typically, there would be some registration API where new users can sign up with their app on their device, which then associates their account with their device ID.

So you would want to look at creating two data setup scripts:

1. a script that creates those users' accounts in the system (e.g. sign up via end user or back office web UI, or API or database script),
2. a script that calls the above registration API.

Then you capture the user data, i.e. device ID, account ID, credentials etc. in a Datapool file (e.g. CSV) for your actual load test script to iterate through.